# Turn Lights On/Off Without Having to Hit 3 Switches in One Room

Tags: lighting, switch, dimmer-switch

I just moved into a new place and I'm having an interesting lighting problem in one of my rooms. I've looked at a few things on the internet, but my lack of experience in this matter makes me feel intimidated by potential solutions.

There are multiple ceiling lights throughout the room and there's a single switch at the entrance, another at a wall, and yet another at a different wall. If I want to turn all of the lights on or off in this particular room, I need to walk around the whole room and flick each switch. I am anticipating getting very annoyed with this.

What I would like to do is have ONE panel at the entrance that will allow me to turn ALL of the lights on or off at once; no walking around the room.

I'm about to buy new light fixtures/bulbs to replace the old ones in the ceiling. Any solution to my issue could potentially involve some sort of smart fixture as well. However, I'm looking for a solution that is relatively inexpensive but still elegant.

Please see my diagrams below to help you understand what the current situation is versus what I would like it to be.

This is the current setup:

[image: test]

This is what I would like it to be:

[image: test2]

Ideally, I'd like a solution that allows me to control each light or light "section/circuit" individually. I think being able to dim the different portions of the room would be great. Additionally, being able to remotely control the different sections would be useful. However, I could live with control from one panel and nothing fancy.

Your suggestions and expertise are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think GE makes bulbs that can be controlled by a smart phone, those might be worth looking in to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, Lutron Pico/Maestro line of remote switches work very well and aesthetically very pleasing.  I would not use nor recommend any other.

In my area Home Depot sells them in white.  For more colors choices you'd need to go through an authorized dealer i.e. a lighting design center or search the internet for availability.

Comment: I did look into Maestro as a potential solution. However, I was unsure about precisely what I would need. Could you give me any more information as to what I should be looking at getting from them?

Comment: Yes, so basically you would replace all three switches with Maestro. And use the Pico wireless remote at the entrance. Then you would program the remote to control all three switches at once. Here's a link from Amazon showing a picture of the maestro next to the Pico wireless controller. http://www.amazon.com/Lutron-MRF2-600MTHW-WH-Multi-Location-Controller-Wallplate/dp/B003U8Y9QA but what is not shown is the Pico wall plate adapter. that is sold separately and functions to hold the wireless device to an existing switch plate. but in your case you may not need it if there is no switch at the e

Comment: ... At the entrance

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm going to look into that further.

Comment: BTW, programming the maestro switches with a pico is a breeze.

Comment: To save you some money just get one maestro and utilize all three switches on one maestro and put dummy switches in place of the other two old switches. Make sure you're not over rating the wattage on the maestro with all your lights on one maestro.

Comment: Do you mean get one Maestro master switch and 2 companions?

Comment: No.  Since you said you want to control all the lights with one switch it doesn't make since to have three maestros unless the wattage of all the lights combined exceeds the 600 watt compacity of 1 maestro.  A companion switch is only necessary if you can control the lights in multiple locations, like a hall or multiple entrance room.

Comment: Or if you just wanted to keep three maestros to operate all 3 lights independently and the Pico controller to turn all on/off that is still fine I just thought you'd might like the idea of saving money.

Comment: I just reread that you do in fact have a switch at the entrance. So that being the case and since you did mentioned you have to walk all the way in the room to turn on lights, I can assume this switch at the entrance does something other than lights? Perhaps it controls outlets? In which case you can still place the wireless pico next to it without the switch box adapter, or spend some time and change the box out to occupy the pico and existing switch. The latter requires a good amount of work. Just a fair warning.

Answer (score 2):

How difficult or expensive it might be would vary with details not provided, but simply rewiring all the lights on to one switch (or all onto one switch panel, multiple switches) is possible with normal switches and wire.

On the other hand, I've become a lot less worried about minmizing number of lights on since the vast majority of mine are drawing 10 watts or less each, and therefore cost me 0.15 cents per hour each to operate; I'm fine with operating larger groups at once, at that sort of operational cost. For a penny an hour (7 x 10W or less LEDs) I'd put them all on one switch or dimmer; but you may want different lighting options with more switches/dimmers - so long as you don't mind paying for them and use dimmers that don't require more fixtures than you want each to control (I think the ones I have currently need 4 fixtures in LED for a minimum load) that's entirely up to you. Simple switches do have the advantage of not having any "minimum load" as the dimmers (and some electronic switches) often do.

Comment: I would really like to avoid rewiring the room.

Answer (score 0):

IF you can get to the wiring (accessible ceiling or floor wiring) then it would be trivially easy to change to the desired arrangement.

An option is to put light operated switches in ONE EACH of the blue and red units and arrange for them to be operated by light from one of the green fixtures.

Various remote operated systems are possible but these will be well enough covered by other answers.